# Calculating ratio or percentage with respect to total sum of num list

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the average of values from the num list

Let's say I have input:

```
list1 = [0, 2, 2, 0 ]
list2 = [5, 10, 5, 0]
```

The output should be:

```
list1_output = [0, 50, 50, 0 ]
list2_output = [25, 50, 25, 0]
```

The purpose is to represent the input as percentage in the chart.
In my case, `len` of the `list` will always be going to be 4, and the `sum` of input can increase from 100 but the `sum` of output should never be more than 100.

Can anybody give me any idea how I can approach this using python?
Pseudo-code also will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with a list comprehension:

```
sum1 = sum(list1)
[i/sum1*100 for i in list1]
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 50.0, 50.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the sum of all elements and divide each element by the sum.

```
list1 = [0, 2, 2, 0 ]
list2 = [5, 10, 5, 0] 

def prcnt(lst):
    sm = sum(lst)
    return [int((l/sm)*100) for l in lst]

print(prcnt(list1))
print(prcnt(list2))
```

---

```
[0, 50, 50, 0]
[25, 50, 25, 0]
```